The sum of Floor function
I am looking of calculating the following Sum.
$\sum\limits_{k=0}^m \lfloor n/2^k \rfloor $ when $l$ is an integer and satisfies $n=2^m+l, 0\le l <2^m$
So far I’ve got $\sum\limits_{k=0}^m \lfloor n/2^k \rfloor = \sum\limits_{k=0}^m \lfloor (2^m+l)/2^k \rfloor = \sum\limits_{k=0}^m 2^{m-k}+ \sum\limits_{k=0}^m \lfloor l
/2^k \rfloor $
How can I calculate the rest?

Clearly, given your restrictions on $l$, we have $\sum_{k\le m} \lfloor l/2^k \rfloor = \sum_{k\le m - 1} \lfloor l/2^k \rfloor $. Might the upper bound on that sum be brought down further? Have you looked at specific values of $l$ and $m$ to see how the latter sum behaves? (Do you know how to handle the first sum?)

I can handle the first sum.
By specifically calculating the latter sum, I assume $\sum\limits_{k=0}^m \lfloor l/2^k \rfloor =2l-m-1$

How did you compute that? Have you tried plugging easy values of $l$ and $m$ into the summation and see if the answer comports with your formula? This might be good to add to your question.

So. The comment about lowering the upper bound on your sum was intended to suggest something about a base-$2$ logarithm -- which in turn may have suggested something about binary. But if you're thinking about a base-$2$ log, maybe you start writing $l = 2^i + j$... and then you realize maybe you don't have to break $n$ up at all :).

You don't need number theory to find a formula for your sum, just $n$'s binary representation, geometric series, and a bit of observation about what your sum(s) is (are) doing. This'll probably make no sense until you see what's going on -- maybe not even then! -- but if you feel like you're repeatedly taking the derivative of a polynomial, you're on the right track :). If you get stuck, update your question with your progress and I'll see if I can help.

When $k\gt \log_2m$ this is the expression for the power of 2 in $m!$
I believe there is no closed form in algebraic functions but there does exist Legendre's formula in your case would be a function of the number's binary representation
